# How do you un-suspend a VM on vSphere Client?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, suspend

It doesn't seem like I can do ANYTHING with this VM now.  I can't unsuspend it back to its normal state.  I can't delete it.  It's like a curse for my datastore.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Is the power on button greyed out?

Comment: Yes, the power on button is greyed out.  I heard it was supposed to have a resume button, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an option, rebooting the ESX host usually clears up this sort of thing.  If your other VMs cannot have downtime, some console-fu might do the trick.

Is this on ESXi or ESX?  ESXi doesn't have a supported console, but [you can still get to it](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-esx-and-vsphere-articles/general/how-to-access-the-vmware-esxi-hidden-console.html).

From the console, vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms will show your virtual machines, and let you figure out the ID of the troublesome one.  You can then use that ID to execute other vmsvc commands.

Actually, [this KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1014165) is a pretty good overview for your initial round of troubleshooting.

Comment: This is on the ESXi.  In the end, I was able to get the problem cleared away with a reboot of the ESXi host.  Thanks for the two helpful links as well. :)